# Give an example of a group of order 8 in which every non-identity element has order 2

Tags: group-theory

This is just an optional question in my homework. It follows the question proving groups with all elements order 2 have to be Abelian. I have done that but I couldnt come up with an example for a group with size 8. Any suggestions?

Comment: gotta love groupthink. This might not be the best question ever posted on the site, but it certainly doesn't deserve 4 downvotes.

Comment: 4 downvotes on a reasonable question, why??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: $$C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Find such a group of order $4$ first.